# How to add select in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add option in select tag but its not working.

```
container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("location"));
var select = document.createElement("select");
var option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.text = "mumbai";
option1.value = "mumbai";
container.appendChild(option1);
container.appendChild(select);
```

Comment: You're adding the `option` element to whatever `container` contains and not the `select`

Comment: i want to add dymiic select option

Comment: dynamic by add buttun

Comment: use [SelectElement.add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add#Creating_Elements_from_Scratch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have add option1 element to select element instead of container element.

Change line:

```
container.appendChild(option1);
```

To:

```
select.appendChild(option1);
```

Comment: Your eplanation says something but your code says something else.

Comment: Why? Its about change element "container" to "select". In code example I just change this and comment this line.

Answer (score 4):

You're adding the option to the container and not to the select. So change `container.appendChild(option1);` to `select.appendChild(option1);`:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('elem')
container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("location"));
var select = document.createElement("select");
container.appendChild(select);
var counter = 0;
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  counter++;
  var option1 = document.createElement("option");
  option1.text = "mumbai" + counter;
  option1.value = "mumbai" + counter;
  select.appendChild(option1);
});
```

```html
<div id='elem'>

</div>
<button name='btn' id='btn'>Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way is to add to `options` list of select.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var options = select.options;
options[options.length] = new Option("Option 1", "1");
options[options.length] = new Option("Option 2", "2");
```

```html
<select id="select"></select>
```

---

[HTMLSelectElement.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add#Creating_Elements_from_Scratch) is another possibility.

```js
var sel = document.createElement("select");
var opt1 = document.createElement("option");
var opt2 = document.createElement("option");

opt1.value = "1";
opt1.text = "Option: Value 1";

opt2.value = "2";
opt2.text = "Option: Value 2";

sel.add(opt1, null);
sel.add(opt2, null);

document.body.appendChild(sel);
```